# What is the work around for TYPE_KEYGUARD now that it's been removed?

Tags: android

I've successfully disabled the notification bar from appearing by using the following code and now I need to upgrade to version 21 of the SDK.

```
    @Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
}
```

However, now I'm getting "cannot find symbol TYPE_KEYGUARD".  Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, it's a simple change:

```
this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
```